# Spring MockMvc ContextListener

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

On my web.xml I have the following listener:

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>
        com.test.listener.MyContextLoaderListener
    </listener-class>
</listener>
```

which is used to, between other things, start my hibernate session. I am using mockmvc to run a few controller tests for my Spring 3.1 project, like this:

```
MockMvc mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.xmlConfigSetup("classpath:application-context-test.xml").build();
```

And, because I am loding from my application-context-test.xml, I dont have access to my web.xml listener configuration. So, I guess my question is:

How do I create a ContextListener to my mockmvc so that I can start my hibernate session there when contextInitialized() is called?

Thanks,

Comment: Is `MockMvcBuilders` your own class? I don't see a `xmlConfigSetup` method.

Comment: No, it's not. It comes from https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-test-mvc, which is what I am using given I am still on Spring 3.1